# Blender game glitch or?

Tags: game-engine

so I'm trying to make a game menu, but both buttons that switch to totally different scenes lead to the same one.There are two planes, and one is connected to one scene, while the other is to another scene. but when i play the game, both scenes go to the same one. help.[image]

Comment: there you go. See with more information, we know what your problem is and can answer.